# Replacing commas with \n, data exports as "undefined", "Cannot find function map in object"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

GOAL: Player submits Google Form indicating which games they would like to sign up for (using checkboxes - data is collected in Column C, labeled "Game"); email is automatically sent confirming their registration (including a list of the games they signed up for) and additional static information / FAQs; Google Sheet indicates that the email was successfully sent. OPTIONAL: Each game that appears in the email confirmation has a hyperlink to a corresponding game page.

Issue #1: Attempt to use .map(function) results in

> TypeError: "Cannot find function map in object".

If I remove the .map and just make the `var gamesHtml = games`, then the script runs okay, but returns an all lowercase, comma delimited list. e.g.

> twist workshop game - oct. 14th 8-10pm est, twist three act - oct. 18th 1-5pm est, twist two act - oct. 23rd 7-10pm est

If I try to remove `.toLowerCase()` from both instances in the script then I get an "undefined" error.

Issue #2 (aka Failed attempt at a work-around): I have a step in the script that replaces the commas with /n from Column C and puts a copy in Column L (labeled "Breakdown"), pulled as var emailList. If I try to call this in function `createEmailBody(name, games, emailList)` / "`emailBody = emailBody.replace(/{{GAMES}}/g, gamesHtml);`" then I get an `undefined` error in the resulting email.

General Question: If I try to do var emailList = responses.Breakdown[0] I receive TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. at onFormSubmit(Code:45). Why is that? What is the purpose of the [0]? (Having trouble "Googling" that question.) Is it because I have line breaks in the cell that it's pulling from?

FWIW, I am not running Chrome V8.

[Google Sheets Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZVKI.png)

```
var EMAIL_TEMPLATE_DOC_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/14aQ-1ekAH_rbcF7S5U4lWRsG_uQQcXvlpQoEXsW3z5k/edit?usp=sharing';
var EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'TWIST Confirmation';

var gameUrls = {
  "TWIST Three Act - Oct. 4th 1-5pm EST": 'http://www.twistvirtual.com',
  "TWIST Workshop Game TBD - Oct. 7th 8-10pm EST": 'http://www.twistvirtual.com',
  "TWIST Three Act - Oct. 10th 12-4pm EST": 'http://www.twistvirtual.com',
  "TWIST Workshop Game TBD - Oct. 14th 8-10pm EST": 'http://www.twistvirtual.com',
  "TWIST Three Act - Oct. 18th 1-5pm EST": 'http://www.twistvirtual.com',
  "TWIST Two Act - Oct. 23rd 7-10pm EST": 'http://www.twistvirtual.com',
  "TWIST Workshop Game TBD - Oct. 25th 2-5pm EST": 'http://www.twistvirtual.com',
  "TWIST Three Act - Nov. 1st 1-5pm EST": 'http://www.twistvirtual.com',
  "I can't make these games but want to play in the future!" : 'http://www.twistvirtual.com',
};

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(e.namedValues);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//gets the spreadsheet you attached the script to
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();//gets whatever sheet is in the front
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();//gets the last row of entered data
   
  var yourColumn = "L";//set your column
  var yourFunction = '=substitute(C'+ lastRow + ',", ",char(10))';//whatever function or formula or data you want, just don't forget to use lastRow do do the row number

  ss.getRange(yourColumn+lastRow).setValue(yourFunction);
 
  var pasted = ss.getRange(yourColumn+lastRow).getValue();
  var listed = pasted.toString().replace(/,/g,'\n');
  ss.getRange("L"+lastRow).setValue(listed);

  Logger.log(listed);


  Logger.log('Attempting to send email')
  
  // If the question title is a label, it can be accessed as an object field.
  // If it has spaces or other characters, it can be accessed as a dictionary.
  var responses = e.namedValues;
  var timestamp = responses.Timestamp[0];
  var email = responses.Email[0].trim();
  var name = responses.Name[0].trim();
  var gamesString = responses.Game[0].toLowerCase();
  var emailList = responses.Breakdown;

  // Parse games of interest into a list (since there are multiple items
  // that are saved in the row as blob of text).
  var games = Object.keys(gameUrls).filter(function(game) {
    // indexOf searches for the game in gamesString and returns a non-negative
    // index if the game is found, or it will return -1 if it's not found.
  return gamesString.indexOf(game.toLowerCase()) != -1;
  });

  // If there is at least one game selected, send an email to the recipient.
  var status = '';
  if (games.length > 0) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: EMAIL_SUBJECT,
      htmlBody: createEmailBody(name, gamesString),
    });
    status = 'Sent '+ new Date();
  }
  else {
    status = 'Error';
  }

  // Append the status on the spreadsheet to the responses' row.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var column = "G";
  ss.getRange(column+lastRow).setValue(status);

  Logger.log("status=" + status + "; responses=" + JSON.stringify(responses));
}

/**
 * Creates email body and includes the links based on game.
 *
 * @param {string} recipient - The recipient's email address.
 * @param {string[]} games - List of games to include in the email body.
 * @return {string} - The email body as an HTML string.
 */

/** ORIGINAL var gamesHtml which returns TypeError: "Cannot find function map in object":
function createEmailBody(name, games) {
  var gamesHtml = games.map(function(game) {
  var url = gameUrls[game];
    return '<li><a href="' + url + '">' + game + '</a></li>';
  }).join('');
  gamesHtml = '<ul>' + gamesHtml + '</ul>';
*/


function createEmailBody(name, games) {
  var gamesHtml = games
  // Make sure to update the emailTemplateDocId at the top.
  var docId = DocumentApp.openByUrl(EMAIL_TEMPLATE_DOC_URL).getId();
  var emailBody = docToHtml(docId);
  emailBody = emailBody.replace(/{{NAME}}/g, name);
  emailBody = emailBody.replace(/{{GAMES}}/g, gamesHtml);
  return emailBody;
}

/**
 * Downloads a Google Doc as an HTML string.
 * 
 * @param {string} docId - The ID of a Google Doc to fetch content from.
 * @return {string} The Google Doc rendered as an HTML string.
 */


function docToHtml(docId) {

  // Downloads a Google Doc as an HTML string.
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=" +
            docId + "&exportFormat=html";
  var param = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, param).getContentText();
}
```

Comment: Firstly, you can't use `.map()` on an object because map is an [Array prototype function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It's odd that anything list-like would be coming back in a non-array format though.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `map()` on a string. That would be the problem with #1.

Comment: `[]` is array. `{}` is object.

Comment: `var emailList = responses.Breakdown[0]` will throw *TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined* if `Breakdown` is `undefined`. The `[0]` is syntax for accessing the first item in an array.

Comment: @zcoop98 - thanks for responding so quickly! Now, I just need to figure out how to use that information to get the desired results. But it at least points me in the right direction. :)